# Value of output of First Reduce Task as <Key Value> pair in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want my first reduce task to produce smth like (course, < sum,count>);
and in second reduce task, I will compute sum/count for each course.
First reducer task acts as combiner, sums and count; 2nd reduce task finds the average and outputs average for each course. I just cannot find what is the best type for storing output value as key-pair and then being able to retrive and do computation on them. HashMap did not work.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

public class AvgGrading {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "avg grading");
        job.setJarByClass(AvgGrading.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MapForAverage.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(ReduceForAverage.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(2);
        job.setReducerClass(ReduceForFinal.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Object.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static class MapForAverage extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Object> {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String [] word = value.toString().split(", ");
            float grade = Integer.parseInt(word[1]);
            int course = Integer.parseInt(word[0]);
            Map <Float,Long> m = new HashMap<Float,Long>();
            m.put(grade, (long) 1);
            con.write(new LongWritable(course), m);
        }
    }

    public static class ReduceForAverage extends Reducer<LongWritable, Object, LongWritable, Object> {
        private FloatWritable result = new FloatWritable();
        public void reduce(LongWritable course, Map<Float,Long> values, Context con)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Map <Float,Long> m = new HashMap<Float,Long>();

            float sum = 0;
            long count =0;
            for (Map.Entry<Float, Long> entry : values.entrySet()) {
                sum += entry.getKey();
                count++;
            }
            m.put(sum, count);

            con.write(course, m);
        }
    }

    public static class ReduceForFinal extends Reducer<LongWritable, Object, LongWritable, FloatWritable> {
        private FloatWritable result = new FloatWritable();
        public void reduce(LongWritable course, Map<Long,Float>values, Context con)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            long key = 0;
            float value=0;

            for ( Map.Entry<Long, Float> entry : values.entrySet()) {
                 key = entry.getKey();
                 value = entry.getValue();
            }
            float res= key/value;

            con.write(course, new FloatWritable(res));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I was not able to iterate through `Iterable < Map<Float,Int>>` in Reduce tasks, so I am passing as simple Map which is probably not correct.

Error code is:

```
Unable to initialize MapOutputCollector org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
```

java.lang.NullPointerException

2nd Reducer fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map doesn't implements Writable and you are saying that your combiner and reducer input value's class is Object, while you're emitting Map .You just need to create a custom class for this purpose. Remember that if you want to emit something in hadoop the custom class must implements Writable. This is something you can do:

```
public class Counter implements Writable {

       private float sum;
       private long count;

       public Counter(float sum, long count){
              this.sum = sum;
              this.count = count;
       }

       /* Methods to get and set private variables of the class */

       public float getSum() {
              return sum;
       }

       public void setSum(float sumValue) {
              sum=sumValue;
       }

       public long getCount() {
              return count;
       }

       public void setCount(long countValue) {
              count=countValue;
       }

       /* Methods to serialize and deserialize the contents of the
          instances of this class */

       @Override /* Serialize the fields of this object to out */ 
       public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException{
              out.writeFloat(sum);
              out.writeLong(count);
       }

      @Override /* Deserialize the fields of this object from in */
      public void readFields(DataInputin) throws IOException{
                  sum=in.readFloat();
                  count=in.readLong();
       }
       }
```

so in your first mapper you can create and emit a counter in this way:

```
       Counter counter = new Counter(grade, 1);
       con.write(course, counter);
```

at this point in your first reducer you will have a key that represent the course and an Iterable value that is an iterable for all the counters and with this iterable you can calculate average. Remember to update mapper an reducers class parameters to be consistent with the new ones.

Comment: Yes, I thought Map itself is an object so it will be able to bypass somehow. I will check your solution, thanks for your time